# Why does the putty MSI get corrupted when I delete a row?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I downloaded putty [from its official website](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html).
I opened it in InstEdit and dropped a row "startmenuManual" from the Shortcut table, made no other changes, saved and reloaded the MSI.

Now the Shortcut table's Directory_ field is now full of null values.  I also used a transform to drop that single row to show all the other tables that have been affected:
[InstEdit screenshot of all tables affected by dropping one row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVeIK.png)

Thinking it was maybe InstEdit causing the issue, I tried with ORCA and got the same result.  I also tried with PowerShell 5.1(x86) and 7.3(x64):

```
$msi = "D:\downloads\putty-64bit-0.79-installer.msi"
$wi = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer
$msiDB = $wi.GetType().InvokeMember('OpenDatabase', 'InvokeMethod', $null, $wi, ($msi,2))
$view = $msiDB.GetType().InvokeMember('OpenView', 'InvokeMethod', $null, $msiDB, "DELETE FROM `Shortcut` WHERE `Shortcut`='startmenuManual'")
$view.GetType().InvokeMember('Execute', 'InvokeMethod', $null, $view, $null)
```

This produced the same result.

I tried again with VBScript but this time it worked and only one row was affected by the change:

```
MSI = "D:\Downloads\putty-64bit-0.79-installer.msi"
Set oInstaller = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Set oDB = oInstaller.OpenDatabase(MSI, 2)
Set oView = oDB.OpenView("DELETE FROM `Shortcut` WHERE `Shortcut`='startmenuManual'")
oView.execute
```

Trying to make further changes with VBScript caused more corruptions.

The Summary Stream reveals this package was made with `Windows Installer XML Toolset ()` It is digitally signed but that shouldn't make a difference when the edit is made via a transform.  I also tried with a previous version with the same results

Can anyone shed any light on what is happening here?